# How to display different directory content with Bash select command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards, select

So far I have found some examples of Bash [select](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-select-56) function usage with [logical constructed options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20698/364080) or [Asterisk one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49568306/2989289) (i.e `select s in *`). *This last one lists all actual directory content.*

**So I would like to understand the following:**

1. What does `*` mean?
2. How could I display another directory content?
   *(I tried something as `opt=$( ls path )` and `select s in "$opt[@]"`, but it fails)*

Any related links or examples are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` is a so-called "[glob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)" and will be expanded by the bash as "all files in the current directory", so it will basically expand to a space-separated list of all files in the current directory (which is the format commonly expected by many bash builtin flow-control constructs).

Globs can be used not only stand-alone but also as part of expressions, so assuming you have a directory stored in a bash variable `$searchdir` (be careful in naming bash variables in order not to accidentally overwrite essential environment variables such as `$PATH`) the construct

```
select s in "$searchdir"/*
```

will expand to "all files in `$searchdir`".

**Note**, however, that if the directory happens to be empty, the expression will amount to *a literal* `*` (or literally `/the/actual/value/pointed/to/by/searchdir/*`) unless you have set the [`nullglob` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239772/bash-iterate-file-list-except-when-empty) via

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Then, if the directory is empty, the glob construct will expand to an empty list which is usually what you will want.